# XSD specifies a target namespace but XML doesn't - can I avoid editing either?

Tags: xml, xsd

A 3rd-party interface provides XML which comes without `<xml>` tag and with no namespace references. The associated XSD file specifies `xmlns` and `targetNamespace` on the `schema` which obviously aren't in the XML.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="cheese"
    targetNamespace="cheese"    
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:element name = "Something>
...
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>

<Something>
 ...
</Something>
```

I can't change the the XML but I can hack my local copy of the XSD. Is the 'best' option just to remove the problem attributes or is there a neater solution?

Comment: I realised I could use an XSLT to modify the returned XML but still wondered which is the better solution (or a 3rd option I haven't thought of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to modify a local copy of a standard schema was indeed one of the motivating factors for parts of the XSD design.

But if I have understood correctly, you are consuming XML produced by a source which is providing an XSD schema for the XML, but publishing XML that doesn't conform to the schema, possibly owing only to a trivial failure to provide a default namespace declaration in the XML.  Other things being equal, I think the best solution in the long run is to inform the source of the XML of this discrepancy.  If they care enough about documentation to provide a schema, the chances are that there may be someone in the organization who also sees the point of validation.  There are no guarantees, of course, but you'd be doing one bit towards making the world a better place.

In the meantime:  yes, local modified copy of the schema, or else use a pre-processor to wrap the XML in a dummy wrapper element of the form

```
<dummy xmlns="cheese">
  ... existing XML goes here, minus XML declaration if any ...
</dummy>
```